# Know when Windows password has changed?

Tags: winapi, vb6

Is there a way to detect when the user has changed their Windows password?

I have written an email client application and users keep forgetting to update the email account password when they change their Windows password (in situations where both are the same). It would be great if I could prompt them to re-enter their password because they'd changed their Windows password.

Comment: You can try periodically reading the event log for the password changed entry. See this link - http://superuser.com/questions/667996/find-when-password-was-changed-windows-sbs-2011

Comment: There's something *very* wrong here.  Why would the mail server's account password match the Windows account password?  They cannot possibly expire at the same time.  Sounds like what you are really trying to do is fool the user with a phishing attack.

Answer (score 0):

How the welcome screen determines if your password is blank is to attempt a logon with a blank password. If it fails it is not blank so it decides to show a password textbox.

You can do the same thing. Attempt to send the mail (or in advance, just attempt logon to the smtp server). If it fails the password is wrong and then prompt.

Comment: And what programming style do you adhere to if not the try, except model. What planet do you come from.

Comment: Ok. Take back my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant to your situation (but I assume you are running in a domain?) but [NetUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) @ level 2 info might do what you want. It has a password-age field that you could use to determine if the password has changed.